# How to Insert id from a Name in Laravel 5.3 Combobox

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to insert the id of the supplier by choosing the name of the supplier from a combo box.

**View**

```
<label for="supplier">Supplier</label>
<input list="supplier" name="supplier" placeholder="Select Supplier" class="form-control">
@foreach($suppliers as $key=>$value)
    <datalist id="supplier">
        <option value="{{$key}}">{{$value}}
    </datalist>
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

public function store(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $product = new Product;
    $request->user()->products()->create($request->all());
}
```

**Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'qty', 'bprice', 'sprice', 'edate'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, user_id);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a product-supplier relation defined in your Product model?

Comment: yes i have - belongsTo (Supplier::class)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
  public function store(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $product = new Product;
    $product->supplier_id = $request->supplier;
    $product->price = $request->price; // if u hv it
```

.         // finish the rest then

```
   $user->products()->save($product);

   // finish the rest

    }
```

Comment: i want to store id but value passes through the combo box.

Comment: show me a request example. in function write this at the top `dd($request->all());` and show me output (select multiple checkboxes)